# Изменение значений в hidden-input

Tags: php, html, веб-программирование

Здравствуйте!

Предположим, есть страница, на которой выводится список пользователей и напротив каждого пользователя есть кнопка "добавить в друзья" или "заблокировать". Логично, чтобы отследить для какого пользователя была нажата кнопка,  её можно разместить вместе с input полем с типом hidden с значением равным id пользователя в базе.

```html
<form method="post">
  <input name="user_id" type="hidden" value="22">
  <input name="add_friend" type="submit" value="Добавить в друзья">
</form>
```

Собственно в таком типе реализации меня мучает следующий вопрос: в отладчике видно все скрытые поля и их значения и пользователю ничего не мешает в hidden-input вставить значение не 22, а, допустим, 100 и таким образом на сервер действительно придет значение user_id = 100, а не 22, напротив которого кнопка была нажата. Получается, что пользователь может таким образом добавить в друзья того, кто даже не прислал ему запрос.

Понятное дело, что должны быть проверки на то, действительно ли был отправлен запрос и т.д. но все же можно как-то избежать или не допустить подмены значения в hidden поле или же есть более лучшее решение для реализации подобного механизма?

Заранее благодарю за ответ!

Comment: Нельзя доверять никаким данным пришедшим с клиента. Вы в любом случае должны делать все (окончательные) проверки на сервере.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hidden поля в html не предназначены для хранения защищенных данных. Их основное предназначение - отправка дополнительных атрибутов при отправке формы с последующей проверкой на сервере, чтобы они не мешали пользователю при заполнении формы.

Таким образом, нельзя полагаться на защищенность данных ни при каких обстоятельствах, если эти данные хранятся на клиенте.

В вашем случае в любом случае необходима проверка на сервере, что добавляемый в друзья пользователь ранее присылал запрос.

Comment: Выходит самый оптимальный вариант, просто проверять входящие данные на сервере?

Comment: @krown_loki на сервере несомненно должны проводиться все необходимые проверки, но для удобства пользователя также реализуют дополнительные проверки на клиенте.

Comment: Спасибо большое!